# How do I 'grep -c' and avoid printing files with zero '0' count

Tags: grep

The command 'grep -c blah *' lists all the files, like below.

```
 % grep -c jill *
 file1:1
 file2:0
 file3:0
 file4:0
 file5:0
 file6:1
 %
```

What I want is:

```
 % grep -c jill * | grep -v ':0'
 file1:1
 file6:1
 %
```

Instead of piping and grep'ing the output like above, is there a flag to suppress listing files with 0 counts?

SJ

Comment: No, I don't believe so--sorry. But, one thing you should do to make your pipe work even if there is only one file in the directory is use the `-H` option: `grep -H -c jill * | grep -v ':0$'`

Answer (score 27):

## How to grep nonzero counts:

`grep -rIcH 'string' . | grep -v ':0$'`

- `-r` Recurse subdirectories.
- `-I` Ignore binary files <sup>(thanks [@tongpu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/56367/33543), warlock)</sup>.
- `-c` Show count of matches. Annoyingly, includes 0-count files.
- `-H` Show file name, even if only one file <sup>(thanks [@CraigEstey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35565533/how-do-i-grep-c-and-avoid-printing-files-with-zero-0-count#comment58821357_35565533))</sup>.
- `'string'` your string goes here.
- `.` Start from the current directory.
- `| grep -v ':0$'` Remove 0-count files. <sup>(thanks [@LaurentiuRoescu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/56357/33543))</sup>

(I realize the OP was excluding the pipe trick, but this is what works for me.)

Comment: Let's add `-D skip` to also ignore devices/sockets/etc.

Answer (score 1):

Just use awk. e.g. with GNU awk for `ENDFILE`:

```
awk '/jill/{c++} ENDFILE{if (c) print FILENAME":"c; c=0}' *
```